# How to use critical css with angular views

Tags: css, angularjs, gruntjs, partials

I want to use grunt-critical (https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-critical)  within the Grunt taskmanager (first time using it) to increase the loadtime of my web application.

The web-app is built on AngularJS with different HTML partials. All my partials are loaded within my  `<div ui-view=""></div>`. However when I try to run grunt-critical on the index (with the `ui-view`) the partials for the homepage are not loaded yet, making it hard for grunt-critical to know which classes are needed for the first render. Is there a way to solve this?

My grunt-critical task is as follows:

```
 test: {
        options: {
            base: './',
            css: 'src/styles/import.less',
            width: 1280,
            height: 960
        },
        src: 'src/statics/index.html',
        dest: 'src/statics/index-critical.html'
    }
```

Thanks guys!